# Using generic collections in arguments

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, collections

Let's say you have:

```
public interface A {}

public class B implements A {}

public class C {
  void foo (List<A>) {}
}

public class Test {
  //Declaration one
  List<A> x = new List<A>();

  //Declaration two
  List<A> x = new List<B>();

  B b = new B();
  x.add(b);


  new C().foo(x);
}
```

Now obviously declaration one is the correct way to do this, and you receive a compile error on declaration two. I would like to know though why Java chooses to enforce type safety in this specific manner; if a list of Cats is still a list of Animals, why does a method expecting a list of animals balk at receiving a bunch of cats?

Curiousity, more than anything else - and a chance to better refine my knowledge.

Cheers,
Dave.

Comment: As a side note, I'm aware we can change the method in C to be the following: void foo(List<? extends A>) {} but I still wonder why that substitution doesn't happen 'automagically' anyway :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Java generics are not *covariant*.  If you could do this:

```
ArrayList<Animal> x = new ArrayList<Cat>();
```

then you would be able to do:

```
x.add(new Dog());
```

which violates the concept that an `ArrayList<Cat>` can only hold `Cat` objects (or subclass objects).

Read this for for more details: [*Java theory and practice: Generics gotchas*](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01255/index.html).

Comment: Thank you good sir. A very helpful link to answer my questions.

Answer (score 9):

> Why does a method expecting a list of animals balk at receiving a bunch of cats?

Because you can add any animal to that list, not just cats. This could result in a list of cats containing a dog, like so:

[image: I think there's a spy aming us …]

The caller still thinks it's a list of cats and a dog dies when the caller tries to make them fall on his feet when dropped.

Answer (score 0):

Use "extends" instead of the class directly :

```
List<? extends A>x;
```

If you use only the class as generic then all the elements mus be only of this class.