# Compile error when providing interface as an arraylist type

Tags: java, interface, arraylist

I have an interface defined as

```
interface ListItem {
    public String toString();
    public String getUUID();
}
```

And a class (`BrowseItem`) implementing that interface. When I try:

```
ArrayList<ListItem> = (method returning ArrayList of type BrowseItem)
```

I get an incompatible type error (`found ArrayList<BrowseItem>, require ...<ListItem>`)

Am I approaching this wrong?

Answer (score 11):

Java generics are not covariant.

See ([among many other questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D%20collection%20covariance)):

- [java generics covariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660827/java-generics-covariance)
- [Java covariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184295/java-covariance-question)
- [Java collections covariance problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763192/java-collections-covariance-problem)
- [Using generic collections in arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370284/using-generic-collections-in-arguments)

---

Solutions:

- Change the return type of the problematic method. That is, change

  ```
  List<listItem> = (method returning List of type browseItem)
  // to
  List<listItem> = (method returning List of type listItem)
  ```
- Use wildcard covariance (I *think* that's what this is called):

  ```
  List<? extends listItem> = (method returning List of type browseItem)
  ```

  Be aware that [**you cannot add items to the list** if you take this route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776975/how-can-i-add-to-list-extends-number-data-structures).

---

<sub>**N.B.** it is generally good practice to declare list types as `List<T>` and not `ArrayList<T>`. The pseudocode above reflects this.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

your example doesnt work, but you can use

```
ArrayList<? extends ListItem> list = (method returning ArrayList of type browseItem)
```

this should work.

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayList<listItem>` is not equal to `ArrayList<browseItem>`

They are strictly type safe

you can make use of `?`