# 2d arraylist and class inheritance in java

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist

assume I have Class A as the parent of Class B and Class C

I initialized two `ArrayList<B>` bList and `ArrayList<C>` cList. 
Then I have another `ArrayList<ArrayList<A>>` bigList.

I want to store bList and cList into that bigList by bigList.add(bList) and bigList.add(cList), and this gives me an error. Anyone have suggestion of how I should fix this or another way of doing it?

Thank you

Comment: What is the error? Also, is bigList an ArrayList<A>?

Comment: probably a covariance issue. Please see:[Problem providing interface as an arraylist type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010913/problem-providing-interface-as-an-arraylist-type-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bigList` should be `ArrayList<ArrayList<? extends A>>` to allow this to work.

Answer (score 0):

To create a list of lists in this situation, you need to use `<? extends A>` to allow subclasses of A, not just A itself.

```
    List<B> blist = new ArrayList<B>();
    List<C> clist = new ArrayList<C>();

    List<List<? extends A>> listofalist = new ArrayList<List<? extends A>>();

    listofalist.add(blist);
    listofalist.add(clist);
```

---

If instead you want to copy the *contents* of the B and C lists into the A list, then you need to use `ArrayList.addAll()`, not `add()`.

`add(Object o)` is for adding individual objects to a list.

`addAll(Collection c)` is for adding all the contents of one list into another list (or other Collection).

See the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) for ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Simply based on what you just wrote, your problem could be that you're trying to this:

```
bigList.add(aList);
```

When you mean to do this:

```
bigList.add(bList);
```