# inheritance & collections related compile error

Tags: java, inheritance, collections, interface

I'm trying to figure out why this code won't compile.

I have interface A extended by interface B.
Class C which implements interface B.

When I call a method that takes in a single object of type A, I can pass in an object of type C and it's fine.

When I call a method that takes in a java.util.List of type A, I cannot pass in a java.util.List of objects of type C. Eclipse generates the following error:
The method addAList(List) in the type Test1 is not applicable for the arguments (List)

Source code example is below.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test1 {

    public void addASingle(A a) {
        return;
    }

    public void addAList(List<A> aList) {
        return;
    }

// **********************************

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test1 t = new Test1();

        C c1 = new C();
        List<C> cList = new ArrayList<C>();
        cList.add(c1);

        t.addASingle(c1); // allowed

        t.addAList(cList);  // The method addAList(List<Test1.A>)
    // in the type Test1 is not applicable for the arguments (List<Test1.C>)
    }

// **********************************

    public static interface A {
    }

    public static interface B extends A {
    }

    public static class C implements B {
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using generic collections in arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370284/using-generic-collections-in-arguments)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A `List<Car>` is not a `List<Vehicle>`. If it was, you could do the following:

```
List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
List<Vehicle> vehicles = cars;
vehicles.add(new Bicycle());
```

and you would end up with a list of cars which contains a bicycle. It would ruin the type-safety of generic collections.

You probably should used a `List<? extends A>` instead of `List<A>`. `List<? extends A>` means: a `List<some class which is A or which extends A>`.

Comment: Will do ... It's telling me I have to wait another minute though! Thanks for the prompt answer :)

Comment: @JB Nizet cList.add(c1); here we are assigning C type object into A type and it works due to inheritance ... understand vary well... but this inheritance would not work in case of List...  why so?

Comment: Because, as I said in my answer, `List<Car>` does not extend `List<Vehicle>`, even if Car extends Vehicle.

Answer (score 1):

It expects List and you are passing List,

Change it to

```
public void addAList(List<? extends A> aList) {
        return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it expects List of type A....write it in your method signature.

```
public void addAList(List<? extends A> aList) {
        return;
    }
```

**by writing this you declare that..your method expects any List which contains any subtype of A.**..This is called wildcard.